# Php - testing if a radio button is selected and get the value

Tags: php

I'm using php. I'd like to know how can I test if a radio button is selected and get the value? i can test if the radio button is selected but i cannot get the value. 
I created a button to test this in my form. First I select a radio button, then i click on the button and it must display a message that says which value i selected and put this value into a variable. In order to test if a radio button is selected i did like this:

```
$selected_radio=$_POST['SINGLE_' . $question->id . $multi_name_adjust . ''];
if ($selected_radio = 'checked'){}
```

Thanks

Comment: Only selected radio buttons (and checkboxes) are sent to the server. If it is not selected, the name won't be in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: You can use javascript to validate the form before send it to the php, or create hidden inputs with value of all radio buttons, then compare and dismiss the selected one...

Comment: The reason your if statement always equals 'checked' is because of the single = in the condition

Answer (score 43):

It's pretty simple, take a look at the code below:

The form:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
  Answer 1 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans1" /><br />
  Answer 2 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans2"  /><br />
  Answer 3 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans3"  /><br />
  Answer 4 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans4"  /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 

$answer = $_POST['ans'];  
if ($answer == "ans1") {          
    echo 'Correct';      
}
else {
    echo 'Incorrect';
}          
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to dynamicaly get the value instead of entered it in the code? i'd like that when the user select a radio button, i can get the value which corresponds to such radio button, but dynamically. thanks again :)

Comment: Please add some code / more info what you mean. Don't understand what you want to reach, with the  code above you get the value that corresponds to the radiobutton that is selcted (but it seems you need something else?)

Comment: for example, you did (if $answer==ans1). ans1 is the value, but you have to put it in the code. I'd like to replace the ans1 by the dynamique value. because the users can create forms through an interface, so they choose their values for each radio button. If they change the value of a radio button to ans90 instead of ans1, i must modify the code to take that in account: (if answer==ans90). That's what i want. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: You need to save this kind of things in a database. Only then you can make it dynamic, and check on the values you want.
I don't know if your interface is generating the code for you users? else you need to generate the good code.

Answer (score 3):

A very more efficient way to do this in php:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="Color">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['Color'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

and for check boxes multiple choice:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="Color[]" multiple> // Initializing Name With An Array
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
// As output of $_POST['Color'] is an array we have to use foreach Loop to display individual value
foreach ($_POST['Color'] as $select)
{
echo "You have selected :" .$select; // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply use    isset($_POST['radio']) so that whenever i click any of the radio button, the one that is clicked is set to the post.

```
 <form method="post" action="sample.php">
 select sex: 
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="male">
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="female">

 <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['radio'])){

    $Sex = $_POST['radio'];
 }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) and ! empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['radio'])) {
        $radio_input = $_POST['radio'];
        echo $radio_input;
    }
} else {

}
?>
<form action="radio.php" method="post">
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="v1"/>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="v2"/>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="v3"/>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="v4"/>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="v5"/>
   <input type= "submit" name="submit"value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add more explanations ?

Comment: Ok first u have to note that the name attribute in input tags is what php and other server side language use to get input of the user.  So i use to give the submit button a name attribute and value. by so doing, i know when the submit button is clicked. That said i  explain the code.   The if(isset($_POST['submit']) checks if any input has the value of submit in this case is the submit button that has it. So the php side will not be executed if the submit button is not clicked. The nested if(isset($_POST['radio']))  checks if any of the radio buttons is checked.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this code

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
Answer 1 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans1" /><br />
Answer 2 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans2"  /><br />
Answer 3 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans3"  /><br />
Answer 4 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans4"  /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset( $_POST['ans'])){  
echo "This is the value you are selected".$_POST['ans'];          
}         
}
?>
```

Comment: isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['ans']) is more than enough. Reduce all of the IF calls, it looks much nicer and takes off extra overhead. Remember, isset can take 2 parameters. Its also a good idea to decide on !empty - for strings use trim() and if INT value, be sure to declare that - is_int() && !is_numeric() or skip the checks if internal code you know for sure is a INT (and not a public form), with intval() - You get a zero return and avoids exceptions on a empty or incorrect type variable. Just a fyi

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it through the GET request:
for example, index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="result.php" method="post">
  Answer 1 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans1" /><br />
  Answer 2 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans2"  /><br />
  Answer 3 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans3"  /><br />
  Answer 4 <input type="radio" name="ans" value="ans4"  /><br />
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="sendPost()" />
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendPost(){
        var value = $('input[name="ans"]:checked').val();
        window.location.href = "sendpost.php?ans="+value;
    };
 </script>
```

this is sendpost.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["ans"]) AND !empty($_GET["ans"])){
    echo $_GET["ans"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

my form:

```
<form method="post" action="radio.php">
   select your gender: 
    <input type="radio" name="radioGender" value="female">
    <input type="radio" name="radioGender" value="male">
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="submit">
</form>
```

my php:

```
   <?php
      if (isset($_POST["btnSubmit"])) {
        if (isset($_POST["radioGender"])) {
        $answer = $_POST['radioGender'];
           if ($answer == "female") {
               echo "female";
           } else {
               echo "male";
           }    
        }else{
            echo "please select your gender";
             }
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: In php we first check if submit button is set to true, then we check if any radio button is set to true or not,if true then do something....