# Trouble declaring variables from a PHP function?

Tags: php, function, variables, radio-button

I'm writing a function used to check POST data, and see if a radio is checked, then if it is, check the correct input. There are a lot of these radio buttons, so I figured writing a function would be easier.

I'm having trouble.

Current Code:

PHP:

```
function foo_check($foo_radio, $foo_1, $foo_2) {

    if ($foo_radio == "1") {

        $foo_1 = "checked";

    } elseif ($foo_radio == "2") {

        $foo_2 = "checked";

    }

}

$radio = $_POST["radio"];

foo_check($radio, $radio_1, $radio_2);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1" <?php echo $radio_1; ?>>1&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" <?php echo $radio_2; ?>>2
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck

Comment: where are you trouble ?? what exactly you want to do??

Comment: whats your trouble be specific

Comment: I think you are using your function parameters the wrong way. Please be more specific on your question.

Comment: You should read up on [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) as it seems you are changing variables inside the function and expecting them to stay that way in some other section of code.

Comment: you have a variable scope issue - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. You are setting `$foo_1`/`$foo_2` inside a function, but they are not available outside that function

Comment: And my guess is you were trying to pass the parameters by `&` reference.

Comment: Your exactly right. I didn't think about the scope. I'm trying to declare variables inside a function to be used outside of a function.

Comment: This link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416099/php-testing-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-and-get-the-value .

Comment: You should use an array and explode and extract.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo_check($foo_radio) {

    if ($foo_radio == "1") {
        return "Radio1 Checked";
    } elseif ($foo_radio == "2") {
        return "Radio2 Checked";
    }

}

$radio = $_POST["radio"];
$result = foo_check($radio);
echo $result;
```