# how to add a radio button condition

Tags: php

Hello everyone how to add a radio button condition to this line

```
(!isset($_POST["email"]) || ($_POST["email"]==""))
```

my radio buttons are configured like this

```
   <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="MONDIAL-RELAY-BELGIQUE" data-lang="be" value="3" /> Par Mondial Relay avec suivi du colis 3 euros
                                    <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" class="choix_livraison" data-nom="POSTE-COLIS-BELGIQUE" value="6.50" checked="checked"> Par poste colis avec garanti a votre domicile 6.50 euros
```

I want to check if email is empty and that MONDIAL-RELAY-BELGIQUE is checked

Comment: I found this that might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416099/php-testing-if-a-radio-button-is-selected-and-get-the-value

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` (*and*) condition together with `!empty`:

```php
if (empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['choix_livraison']))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is it possible to choose
data-name="MONDIAL-RELAY-BELGIUM"
for condition

Comment: @albert No, because form is using `name` attribute for variables in payload, not `data-name`

Comment: thanks for the help
How then to check if the radio button
data-nom="POSTE-COLIS-BELGIQUE" is checked

Comment: PHP does not have access to any of DOM elements, so you can not do that. You can change name to `name="name[POSTE-COLIS-BELGIQUE]"` so that in PHP you get array `$_POST['name']['POSTE-COLIS-BELGIQUE'] ?? null`